# How to implement Twitter Bootstrap Framework in IBM Websphere Portal 8 for custom theme?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just go through the bootstrap framework, its a grid based css framework but I dont know how implement in IBM Websphere Portal 8.

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<body class="lotusui30dojo tundra locale_en">    
    <div class="wpthemeFrame"> 
        <header role="banner">
    <div class="wpthemeHeader"> 
        <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:customTheme_preview"></a> 
    <div class="wpthemeInner"> 
    <div class="wpthemeLogo wpthemeLeft">
```

Comment: HI Avrill, I have make few changes in theme_en.html here is the code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body class="lotusui30dojo tundra locale_en"> 
 
 <div class="wpthemeFrame">
  
  <header role="banner">

   <div class="wpthemeHeader">
    <a rel="dynamic-content" href="dyn-cs:id:customTheme_preview"></a>

    <div class="wpthemeInner">
     <div class="wpthemeLogo wpthemeLeft">

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a normal static HTML Prototype using Bootstrap. Once you make sue it's working properly (in responsive manner) you can start porting the source code to Portal.  There are 3 parts:

1. First you have to copy paste the html part other than the middle content area (ie. the header part and the footer part) into theme_en.html in your custom folder. Then replace the css and JS links header part with

Then replace blocks of code with appropriate Dynamic Spot contents (JSP files). For instance something like,

```
<a rel="dynamic-content" href="res:/customTheme/themes/html/dynamicSpots/banner.jsp"></a>
```

Also, please make sure at the end of page you have this,

```
<div class="wpthemeComplementaryContent" id="wpthemeComplementaryContent" role="region" aria-labelledby="wpthemeComplementaryContentText">
<span class="wpthemeAltText" id="wpthemeComplementaryContentText" >Complementary Content</span>
<a rel="dynamic-content" href="co:config"></a>
</div>
```

2. Now we have to take the layout structure from the middle part of HTML area and use it for creating a Template Layout. Remember, in each template layout we have to keep the div for hidden widgets. Better way is to copy one existing layout.html file from Template Layouts and rename it and modify in that. If you are using Bootstrap, you don't have to use default WP classes. But few must be integrated, like DndRow,DndColumn, Componet-Container etc.

   3. Now for each page specific styling, you can manage in Presentation template.